# Regex For digit count in an alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, regex

How can i validate following logic from regex

- Allow Dollar($),Comma(,),Decimal(.) and digit(0-9)
- Can have only 8 digit before Decimal irrespective of $ and comma
- 2 digit after decimal

Allowed string Example:

- 99999999.99
- $99999999.99
- $9,999,9999.99
- $9999,99,99.99

Does not allow :
 - $999999999.99 ( 9 digit before decimal)
 - $99,99,999,99.99

Mean i want to restrict the count of digit only before decimal. 
How can i achieve this. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does it _have_ to be done entirely in regexp?

Comment: ^(\$?(\,?\d){1,8}\.\d{2})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^\$?(?:,?\d){1,8}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iE7zA7/2)

**Explanation:**

```
^              # Line start
\$?            # match optional $ at start
(?:,?\d)       # Match an optional comma followed by a digit and use non-capturing group
{1,8}          # up to 8 occurrence of previous group
(?:\.\d{1,2})? # followed by optional decimal point and 1 or 2 digits
$              # line end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(\$?(\,?\d){1,8}\.\d{2}$)/gm
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iI1wQ7/1)

Comment: Sometimes I wonder! Similar answers within seconds from each other are perfectly fine but why post exact duplicate of my answer after 20 minutes?

Comment: if you look closer you will see that they are not the exact same strings